# Удаление пробелов на PHP

Tags: php, замена

```
str_replace('  ', '', $string);
str_replace('   ', '', $string);
str_replace('    ', '', $string);
```

Как мне заменять более двух пробелов одним кодом на ничего('')?

trim() не предлагать, это не то.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Регекспом:

```
$string=preg_replace('/ {3,}/','',$string);
        /*  |          | ||     |   |_в $string
            |          | ||     |_на пустую строку
            |          | ||_и более раз
            |          | |_встреченный 3 
            |          |_пробел (только пробел, для табов и пр символов - \s
            |_заменить 
        */
```

Comment: @eicto, оперативно. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Прекрасный комментарий.